# How to make Python requests work through SOCKS proxy in Colab

Tags: python-requests, proxy, google-colaboratory, socks

```
import requests
import socks
import socket

proxy_host = "xxxxx"
proxy_port = 1080
proxy_username = "aaaaaa"
proxy_password = "cccc"

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxy_host, proxy_port, username=proxy_username, password=proxy_password)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

response = requests.get("https://api64.ipify.org/")

print(response.text)
```

on my own computer this code works correctly. but in virtual environments like colab and azure it doesn't work. i tried many methods but it didn't work. what can i do?